# Indroductory books about Philosophy for young people

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for a book about philosophy to give me a push or to help me get in touch with philosophy properly.

Comment: There are thousands of philosophy books published in many different countries over the course of thousands of years.  Can you narrow it down?  Are you looking for a good introductory texts?  If so, I think there are several other questions here that cover the same ground.

Comment: Bertrand Russell, [The Problems of Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Problems_of_Philosophy).

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Young-Persons-Guide-Philosophy-Jeremy/dp/0789430746

Comment: @K.M. That just repeats your original question.   I've never heard anyone refer to "*the* Philosophy," given how many different philosophies there are.  Do you mean [the perennial philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perennial_philosophy)?  The [love of wisdom](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/philosophy)?  The [discipline of philosophy?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy) Are you looking for an introduction, overview or summary of the entire topic?  Or are you just looking for a definition of the word?

Comment: @JohnAm While your edit seems like the most reasonable way to interpret the original question, I'm not entirely convinced that's what he or she meant.

Comment: @Chris Sunami I checked the profile of the user and he is 16 yo. I think if i was in his age i would like something similar to what i pointed out. Personally i have started from Epicurus (around 14) and that is what i would suggest but i suppose a general survey in a friendly approach suits better.

Comment: It's possible people around here are confusing Philosophy Stack Exchange with the School of Athens.

Comment: At the age of twelve (or so) I read [Sophie's World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie%27s_World). While not 100% accurate in terms of academic interpretations, it gives an idea of some basics of philosophy and has been an incentive for me for going deeper into it.